# How do I use differential equations to solve a problem with a falling, unknown mass?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on a problem regarding where I'm given an object that's being thrown upwards with a certain velocity, but I'm not given the mass. I know that acceleration is independent of mass, but the only Newtonian differential equation I know is $F(v,t) = m {dv\over dt}$ and obviously I need to use the mass for this equation. I have to find the amount of time it takes the object to hit the ground and how fast it's moving when it does. My approach to solving the problem is this:

$1)$ Find the maximum height the ball reaches (I just used a kinetics equation for this)

$2)$ Then using $d=rt$ I can find how long it takes the ball to reach the ground.

So for this I don't need differential equations to solve the problem, but my instructor wants me to. And for finding how fast the object is moving when it hits the ground I thought that I needed to know the mass of the object for this, too.

How do I approach this problem using DE?

Comment: If the only force on the mass is gravity, then the mass will divide out. The "differential equation" will really only be a function of acceleration, so integrating twice and deriving the kinematics equations is how the problem will go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The force from gravity is $-mg$, so the mass divides out when you write $m \frac {dv}{dt}=-mg$  You can integrate this twice to get the usual $z=z_0+v_0t-\frac 12gt^2$ where $z_0$ is the starting altitude and $v_0$ is the starting velocity.  Setting $v=0$ gives the time to maximum altitude as $\frac {v_0}g$.  If $z_0=z$ you spend as long going up as coming down so the total flight time is $\frac {2v_0}g$